Was there an economic reason for Protestants' iconoclasm?
Europe underwent major economic upheavals during the creation of Protestantism (cf. E. Michael Jones, Barren Metal or Goy Guide to World History). Is this one reason why Protestants upheld iconoclasm? Was it a sense of necessity or utilitarianism (that having a minimally decorated church is better than having no church at all) that inspired or justified their iconoclasm?
In other words: Was there an economic reason for Protestants' iconoclasm?

Here is a link to a contemporary etching by Franz Hogenberg (German, ca. 1540– ca. 1590) of Calvinists smashing church icons.

It refers to teachings of John Calvin about the role of images in worship and the actions it inspired among his followers. A quote from the article (not from Calvin):

Images, according to Calvin, held no religious relevance. Worse,
images could lead to idolatry, the worship of the picture rather than
the thing that it represented. In the summer of 1566, spurred on by
the sermons of Calvinist preachers, zealous mobs descended on churches
in the Netherlands, intent on ridding them entirely of their imagery.
Many churches were literally white-washed.

Later in the article, the political situation is mentioned. The people of the Netherlands wanted to shake off Spanish rule:

Although its subject matter is the desecration of the house of God,
Hogenberg’s etching is equivocal. To the left of the church, finely
dressed on-lookers remark on the happenings taking place inside, while
others stroll by without even noticing the destruction. However, to
the right, the mob’s assault extends into the street, where
participants begin to plunder local shops. Hogenberg shows both order
and disorder in the events, which were prompted by conflicting
attitudes about art and religion and helped to precipitate the Dutch
Revolt against Spanish Catholic rule in the Netherlands.


A "sense of necessity or utilitarianism" wasn't at play because Protestants took over Catholic churches and destroyed (didn't resell) their artwork. The word εἰκονοκλάστης means “image breaker”.
Gardner, Helen, and Fred S Kleiner. 2010. Gardner’s Art through the Ages: A Concise Western History. 2nd ed. Australia: Wadsworth Cengage Learning p. 254:

In an episode known as the Great Iconoclasm, bands of Calvinists visited Catholic churches in the Netherlands in 1566, shattering stained-glass windows, smashing statues, and destroying paintings and other artworks they perceived as idolatrous.


So your own answer boils down to... theology ;)

They destroyed what they they did for the same reason that idols were ground to powder and scattered in the brook Kidron (Cedron). It was passionate zeal for the Lord their God and his holy Person which urged the destruction of all that misrepresented his true Deity.
